Visual Studio Code crash issue "kill-9". Linux Mint
I'm working on a React project built with the Yarn package manager.VsCode crashes periodically with the following error : "The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of memory or someone called kill -9 on the process".
I have no problems with projects built with npm on the same computer. Or I even run Docker locally for some projects, but I don't have any problems.As far as I understand, the RAM of my laptop is not enough for instant operations. Or something else? I can't check Task Manager or CPU Manager because I lose all screen control when the application crashes.
Is there a way to solve this problem with VsCode or computer configurations?
Notebook:
product: VivoBook_ASUSLaptop X515EP_X515EP
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-3.3.0 dmi-3.3.0 smp vsyscall32
*-core;
product: X515EP
slot: MIDDLE
*-memory;
description: System Memory
slot: System board or motherboard
size: 8GiB
*-cpu;
description: CPU
product: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz
version: 6.140.1
size: 2466MHz
capacity: 4200MHz
width: 64 bits
clock: 100MHz
System:  Distributor ID:    Linuxmint Description:  Linux Mint 21.3 Release:    21.3 Codename:  virginia
VsCode:  Version: 1.88.1 Date: 2024-04-10T17:34:12.840Z Electron:
28.2.8 ElectronBuildId: 27744544 Chromium: 120.0.6099.291 Node.js: 18.18.2 V8: 12.0.267.19-electron.0 OS: Linux x64 5.15.0-105-generic

Buy more RAM. With the data provided there's no way anyone could possibly give you a targeted suggestion.
